# añadir fecha en español en python formato %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ

Tags: python

estoy intentando añadir la ultima fecha de la api:

```
https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=lebron%20james&searchLanguage=es

en la linea: shopHistory
```

Pero no consigo que aparezca la fecha en español

Aquí dejo el código completo:

```
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "es_ES")


response = requests.get(f"https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=lebron%20james&searchLanguage=es")

visiteShop2 = response.json()['data'][0]['shopHistory']



d1 = datetime.strptime(max(visiteShop2),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")


print(d1)
```

El codigo funciona correctamente, pero la fecha aparece:
[image]

Me gustaria que apareciese:
2023-04-03 00:00:00
3/4/2023

Alguien me podria ayudar?, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo único que te hace falta es agregar `strftime` para poder darle el formato que deseas.

Ejemplo únicamente mostrando el formato `día/mes/año hora:minuto`:

```
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "es_ES")


response = requests.get(f"https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=lebron%20james&searchLanguage=es")

visiteShop2 = response.json()['data'][0]['shopHistory']
d1 = datetime.strptime(max(visiteShop2), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(d1)
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
03/04/2023 00:00
```